# Pandas dataframe Groupby with NO aggregation

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe and i would like to groupby but get the countries in one cell

Brand                   Model                    Country

IPhone                    6                            UK

IPhone                    7                            DE

IPhone                    6                            US

IPhone                    7                            FR

IPhone                    6                            IT

IPhone                    7                            NL

I would like to have this result would this be posssible

Brand                    Model                        Country

IPhone                    6                             UK - US - IT

IPhone                    7                             DE - FR - NL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df = df.groupby(['Brand', 'Model']).agg({'Country': lambda x: '-'.join(x)}).reset_index()
```

result:

```
   Model   Brand   Country
0      6  iphone  UK-US-IT
1      7  iphone  DE-FR-NL
```

Comment: you probably want to groupby the model and brand columns. consider the scenario where a different phone (leak the pixel) also as a model "7". You also don't need the `"%s" %` part in your agg function. `lambda x: '-'.join(x)` suffices

Comment: As a matter of fact, `'-'.join` should suffice - `lambda x: func(x)` is the same as `func`. Great solution nonetheless!

Comment: @fsimonjetz great point! adding the `lambda x: ` is burned into my muscle memory to follow groupby+apply/agg and I forget you don't always need it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
out = (df.groupby(['Brand', 'Model'])
         .agg({'Country':'unique'})
         .applymap(lambda x: ' - '.join([str(val) for val in list(x)]))
         .reset_index()
        )
```

###### `>>> display(out)`

[image]